# VBA Run-time Error: 249 - Only occurs when Schtasks

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT**: Turns out this error only occurs when an instance of Outlook is already running.

This is a strange error. I've setup a macro to automatically execute every morning after it's downloaded a report.

The macro is executed by this VBS code:

```
Dim xl
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory

xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(strCurDir & "\TodaysScript.xlsm")
xl.Application.Visible = False
xl.Application.run "'TodaysScript.xlsm'!autoOpen"

xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Quit

Set xl = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

`autoOpen` is the name of the macro which I am running (I purposely avoided `Auto_Open`)

Everything works fun when I run the script, but the moment the script is executed via `schtasks` it will return this error:

[image]

When debugging, it shows up here:

[image]

I've done a lot of reading, the KB article didn't help.

It's just very strange how it'll work if I double click my VBS and execute it normally, but the moment I execute it via `schtasks` it comes up with an error.

Here is the schtask query

```
schtasks /create /tn "Reports" /tr %file% /sc weekly /st 10:00:00 /d MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /V1
```

**I might also add:** this was working yesterday, but now it has stopped working on both my computer, and a colleges' computer.

Comment: Could it possibly be a permissions issue? Not entirely in the realm of these languages, but I've written batch files to be executed by a SQL Server Agent job where if I just double-click the .bat file, it runs fine, but when the actual job runs it, it gives a permissions error for the account the task runs as.

Comment: I was also thinking that. How could I programmatically change the user executing the VBA?

Comment: I also believe it is a permissions issue. Give `schtasks` admin rights to execute the script and it will be ok.

Comment: Does the account used in `schtasks` has valid email account on the domain? I tried run a vbs with an account that does not have email associated, and it brings up Outlook Account Setup wizard. Do you have an account that are used in automation (or spare email enabled account for I.T. purposes)?

Comment: Yes it does have a valid email account. It's odd because this was working yesterday, although we are on a network which has push policies that may change some environmental elements.

Comment: Turns out that this only occurs when an instance of Outlook is already running.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments on your question, if it's a permissions issue, you can change the user it runs as when you run the command, here's the syntax

```
schtasks /Create 
[/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
[/RU username [/RP [password]] /SC schedule [/MO modifier] [/D day]
[/M months] [/I idletime] /TN taskname /TR taskrun [/ST starttime]
[/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] 
[/XML xmlfile] [/V1]] [/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I wanted to run this as an administrator, would I use `/S localhost /U administrator` - I would like this script to be portable to any computer, how can I make it prompt for a password?

Comment: According to the parameter description, if you omit the password it will automatically prompt for it. /P [password]
A value that specifies the password for a given user context. If omitted, Schtasks.exe prompts the user for input.